# Scaling/Downsampling with Newrez results in trapped mouse

Tags: 16.04, monitor, xrandr

I've used newrez in the past with older notebooks and it has always worked like a charm. Now I've bought a newer computer and at first it didn't work because it didn't detect an LVDS1 display, and after researching I found out I had an eDP1 display and used gedit to replace all instances of LDVS1 with eDP1 on the newrez file. This made scaling work, but mouse got trapped in an invisible area the size of the older resolution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a while investigating on my own... I figured this out. If anyone has the same problem, where you get a "Current display must be LVDS1" error then you probably have a notebook with eDP1 display. If that's the case then just create an empty file and paste this inside. This is the code for "newrez" but I changed some stuff so that it works with eDP1 displays. If you have LVDS1 then you should use the original newrez.

Save the file however you want to call it, I saved it as newrez-edp1 and then mark it as executable. Run it and select the resolution you want to use.

Hopefully this will save you some investigation time.

```
#!/bin/bash

# newrez

# Marc Brumlik, Tailored Software Inc, tsi-inc@comcast.net

# up to v 0.8
# use 'xrandr' to scale video output to the display

# v 0.9
# Wed Jan  2 05:23:54 CST 2013
# rewrite to handle mouse boundaries when scaled (mouse confined)
# by setting requested resolution to the unused VGA1 device
# then scaling that for display on the LVDS1 device

# v 1.1
# Fri Dec 20 08:28:08 CST 2013
# fixed issue where setting to "default" after some other resulution
# left mouse-area at prior resolution

# v 1.1 for eDP1 Thu Jan 13
# Changed some code for this to be compatible with eDP1
# All credit goes to original creator

umask 000

# resolution can optionally be specified on command line
newrez=$1

# we MUST be running xrandr 1.3 or higher
if xrandr -v | grep "RandR version 1.[012]"
    then    zenity --info --title="XRandR version is too old" --text="You must be running Xrandr
version 1.3 or newer!
Time to upgrade your system  :-)"
        exit 0
fi

# find the currently connected devices, make a list
devices=`xrandr -q | grep connected | grep -v disconnected | cut -d"(" -f1`

# there MUST be a "connected" LVDS1 and a "disconnected" VGA1
current=`xrandr -q`

if echo "$current" | grep "eDP1 connected" >/dev/null
    then    : OK
    else    zenity --info --title="PROBLEM" --text="Current display must be eDP1"; exit 0
fi

default=`echo "$current" | grep -A 1 "^eDP1" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
H=`echo $default | cut -d'x' -f1`
V=`echo $default | cut -d'x' -f2`
HZ=`echo $default | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '[*+]'`

# echo DEFAULT: $default $H $V

if [ -z "$newrez" ]
    then    while true
        do
            newrez=`zenity --entry --title="Set New Resolution" \
                --text="Default Resolution: $default\n\nNew size (eg 1280x750 or 1450x1000)\n   -or- \"default\""` || exit 0
            case $newrez in
                default|[0-9]*x[0-9]*)  break ;;
            esac
        done
fi

case $newrez in
    default)    xrandr --output eDP1 --mode $default --scale 1x1 --panning $H"x"$V
            xrandr --addmode VGA1 $default
            xrandr --newmode $default $newmode
            xrandr --output VGA1 --mode $default --scale 1x1 --panning $H"x"$V
            exit 0 ;;
esac

newH=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f1`
newV=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f2`
modeline=`cvt $newH $newV $HZ | grep Modeline`
newmode=`echo "$modeline" | sed 's/^.*"//'`
cvtrez=`echo "$modeline" | sed -e 's/_.*//' -e 's/^.*"//'`

if [ "$newrez" != "$cvtrez" ]
    then    newrez=$cvtrez
        newH=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f1`
        newV=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f2`
fi

scaleH=`echo -e "scale=10\n$newH / $H\nquit" | bc`
scaleV=`echo -e "scale=10\n$newV / $V\nquit" | bc`

if echo "$current" | grep -A 100 "^VGA1" | grep $newrez >/dev/null
    then    : already there
    else    xrandr --newmode "$newrez" $newmode
        xrandr --addmode VGA1 $newrez
fi

if xrandr --output VGA1 --mode $newrez --output eDP1 --fb $newrez --scale $scaleH"x"$scaleV --panning $newH"x"$newV 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/xrandr.err 
    then    : success
    else    zenity --info --title="Xrandr produced this error" --text="`cat /tmp/xrandr.err`"

The problem could be that Your video driver
does not support xrandr version 1.3
        rm -f /tmp/xrandr.err
fi
```

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: It does. I have edited this same file by replacing the eDP lines with HDMI or whatever the 'xrandr' command outputs as the current screen, and I've been able to scale successfully.